# This project(Visual Studio 2012 express) is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio 2013 express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, backend, backwards-compatibility

Am doing a back end project in C# in Visual Studio. My team mate had done it using Visual Studio 2012 express and everything seems to work there. But when i used git to clone it to my system where am using Visual Studio 2013 express, one part of the project says its incompatible with the current version of VS. I could clean and build the project, but was unable to run the project. I searched and found that one solution is to go to Programs and features, select VS, right click,select repair. But even after doing this, the problem persists. Is there any work around?

Comment: Your friend can use some special project, like InstallShield installer or another addon into Visual Studio... In this case, if you don't have this addon installed, project will be unavailable to you.

Answer (score 3):

When I was learning ASP.NET MVC by Informit tutorials I was in the very similar situation. I downloaded the sample sources that was created in VS2013 but had VS2015 installed. It was some kind of bug \ magic, but VS didn't recognized some libraries in VS2015 even they were installed. What is more strange is the fact that when I decided to totally rewrite the project line by line it worked!

Of course, I tried to clean, rebuild, reinstall NuGet packages.

So, if you have an access to sources *.cs, then just try to create new project and copy-paste code.

Comment: But its already on git..So, I dont want to create another copy of the code and upload again.